# Artisan not able to detect application namespace

Tags: php, laravel

Very recently, my application stopped working properly for some reason and I had to change my application namespace, so it is projectname\Model instead of App\Model.

Now after this change, everything started working normally, except php artisan commands.

When I call `php artisan`, I can have the lists of artisan commands but none works, I always get `[RuntimeException] Unable to detect application namespace.`. 
For exemple, I tried running `php artisan make:controller ShoppingCartController` and I get this error.

I looked online and a lot of people say it's a problem with the composer.json, but I tried `composer diagnose` and nothing stands out, and I updated composer and also tried `composer dump-autoload`.

And in my composer.json, I have this part I changed recently:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "projectName\\": "App/"
    }
},
```

And I carefully looked to be sure there was no extra comma in the .json.

I'd like to still be able to use php artisan commands so I'd like to solve this.

Thanks,

Comment: the line `"projectName\\": "App/"`, are you sure your app directory is with capital 'A' and not lowercase? Try with lowercase and see ``"projectName\\": "app/"`

Comment: That was actually it. I can't believe it was something as simple as that! Thanks Eddy.

Comment: Please, mark my answer as the solution. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rename your default namespace, the second parameter should be the name of the 'app' folder. so instead of

```
"projectName\\": "App/"
```

You should have

```
"projectName\\": "app/"
```